# In asp.net API HttpGet{id} works but when I change the {id} to something else it dose not work

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Im pretty new to ASP core webAPI.  Hopefully you guys can give me a hand.

I have been successfully using HttpGet{id} - postman has been serving the correct information back.  However, I want to be able use "partNumber" in the url.

below is the working id get method:

```
'''
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
     public async Task<ActionResult<Model>> GetModel(int id)
        {
        return await _context.Models.FindAsync(id);
        }
'''
```

Here is the actual parameters that I would like to search on:

````
```

[HttpGet("{PartNumber}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Model>> GetModel(int partNumber)
        {
          return await _context.Models.FindAsync(partNumber);
        }
        
```
````

Postman returns 404 not found in the latter when I should see data returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 means the request url is not correct.

Here is my whole backend code and my controller contains `[Route("api/[controller]")]` attribute:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{partNumber}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Model>> GetModel(int partNumber)
    {

    }
}
```

The request url should be:`https://localhost:44371/api/tests/YourPortNumber`(https://localhost:44371/api/tests/1).

Result:

[image]

For NoContent return in postman,please set breakpoint and check if database contain such record with the specific partNumber:

```
 [HttpGet("{partNumber}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Model>> GetModel(int partNumber)
{
      //set breakpoint here...
      var data = await _context.Models.FindAsync(partNumber);
      return await _context.Models.FindAsync(partNumber);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can get up to where you are above so partNumber is holding the correct url value but the the return line isn’t returning the values back into postman. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: You mean `return await _context.Models.FindAsync(partNumber);` does not return value back?You need set breakpoint and check if it has value.Add `var data= await _context.Models.FindAsync(partNumber);` and check if have data.If my answer helped you,please accept as answer.Thank you~

Comment: I'm I right in thinking: In your example, you are still search the data via the id?  I want to search my data via a column in my database names "partNumber" instead.  Can this be done?  

I have the a column named partNumber, within one of the rows it has a value of 1724340.  I can see this in my Database.  When I set the breakpoint, I can see that the partNumber (1724340) being passed into the method but the "data" variable shows null.

Comment: Hi @Gavin,because FindAsync method get the value for id,if partNumber is not your id,you need try:`var data = _context.Models.Where(a => a.PartNumber== partNumber).ToList();`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpGet("{partNumber}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Model>> GetModel(int partNumber)
    {
      return await _context.Models.FindAsync(partNumber);
    }
```

The casing of the string in the route should match the parameter